# Ubuntu USB install hangs at purple loading screen on HP Pavillion x360

Tags: system-installation, usb, mount, 15.04

I've been trying to install the latest 15.04 Ubuntu on my laptop through a usb installation, but whenever I try the "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" prompts, the screen hangs at a loading screen that's going no where. I've made sure the MD5 checksum matches up, and I'm positive that the USB is fine.

When I press F4 during the loading screen I get this:

> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>
> Failed to mount 'dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
>
> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>
> Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting, or mount the volume read-only
>
> with the 'ro' mount option.
>
> mount: mounting dev/sda4 on /cdrom failed: No such device

I've disabled the fast start up option as well ensuring my Windows did a full shut down. Previous editions of Ubuntu have worked for me, so I'm suspecting it's an issue with the kernel, or the fact that I'm running Windows 10 technical preview. When I've used many linux distros, after upgrading to the latest software upon install, the distro will often fail to boot under the latest kernel, forcing me to choose an earlier kernel to boot into.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm trying to use Ubuntu as the only OS on this laptop.

Comment: I'm trying to install ubuntu 15.04 on the same laptop. I got stuck 2 times on the purple screen, and once I got a black screen, but I could hear the drums indicating ubuntu had started. I assume I am missing graphics drivers. Did you solve your issue ? If so, how ?